# Date/Time as string in Access SQL - Select a specific date

Tags: sql, ms-access

I would like run a SQL in MS Access like the following:

```sql
SELECT Time, Ask, Bid
FROM AUDCAD
WHERE Time LIKE '2016.10.05'
ORDER BY ID;
```

However the result is nothing, The Time field data is look like the following:

```
2016.12.05 09:42:17.026
2016.12.05 09:42:17.387
2016.12.05 09:42:17.951
2016.12.05 09:42:18.464
...
2016.12.06 09:24:41.449
2016.12.06 09:24:41.854
2016.12.06 09:24:42.258
```

Therefore, I would like to extract the data day by day (this example: 2016.10.05)

Can anyone help me to solve this problem?

Lawrence
[image]

[image]

Comment: It looks like your [Time] column is Text. In that case try `...  WHERE [Time] LIKE '2016.10.05 *'`.

Comment: I tried the code following: SELECT [Time], Ask, Bid 
FROM AUDCAD 
WHERE [Time] LIKE '2016.10.05 *' 
ORDER BY ID;                                      the output is the blank sheet

Comment: Hmm. Try `... WHERE [Time] ALIKE '2016.10.05 %'` and see if that works any better. (BTW, you *do* have entries for October 5, 2016 in the table, right?)

Answer (score 0):

You need to check two things first...

1. Did your insert query work without errors .. are you sure time '2016.10.5' data exist in your DB?
2. Can you execute standard query to get time data and it works? Meaning can you 'SELECT FROM AUDCAD" ang get time data 2016.10.5

Comment: "Select Time from AUDCAD"

Comment: 1. yes, insertion without error, the time 2016.10.05 does exist in the DB, see the edited original post

Comment: 2. no. I can't execute to get time, that is what I want to do so, this is also my question. the problem is time is too long, not only 2016.10.05. Time comprise [year.month.day hour:min:sec.millisec] . therefore, no duplicate time in DB

Answer (score 0):

You must use the proper syntax for date expressions in Access SQL:

```
SELECT [Time], Ask, Bid
FROM AUDCAD
WHERE [Time] = #2016/10/05#
ORDER BY ID;
```

or, if Time has a time component:

```
SELECT [Time], Ask, Bid
FROM AUDCAD
WHERE Fix([Time]) = #2016/10/05#
ORDER BY ID;
```

However, it looks like you retrieve data from a *DateTime2* field in SQL Server.

Thus, either change the data type to *DateTime*, or use the SQL Native Driver version 10 or 11 for your ODBC connection. If not, you will receive the date/time as text, not date/time values.

Comment: I tried both 2 sql codes and didn't work, I am not sure how to check the data type. Can the edit screenshot reveal it (see original post)?

Comment: It is text. Go to design view of the table. I guess you have imported those values from somewhere. @Gord's method will work in that case.

Comment: Plz see the original edited post for my latest pic. How should I do?

Comment: Either import the data again, this time obtaining the Time field as a Date value - or leave it as is and follow @Gordon's method.

Comment: I renamed Time field to Date and I tried the code following: SELECT Date, Ask, Bid FROM AUDCAD WHERE Date LIKE '2016.10.05 *' ORDER BY ID; the output is the blank sheet

Comment: Renaming the field doesn't change anything - other than now you use a reserved word as field name, thus it must be bracketed: `SELECT [Date], Ask, Bid FROM AUDCAD WHERE [Date] LIKE '2016.10.05 *'`.

Answer (score 0):

The separator for DateTime fields is `#`. Ex: #12/30/2016#.
I would recommend to always use the american order in VBA (m/d/y) even if the local machine is configured otherwise. It works fine that way.

Answer (score 0):

Your sample query

```sql
SELECT Time, Ask, Bid
FROM AUDCAD
WHERE Time LIKE '2016.10.05'
ORDER BY ID;
```

uses a LIKE clause without any wildcards, so `WHERE Time LIKE '2016.10.05'` behaves just the same as `WHERE Time = '2016.10.05'`. That won't return any rows because the [Time] column always includes some characters after the date.

By default, Access uses the asterisk (`*`) as the "0 or more characters" wildcard, so

```sql
SELECT Time, Ask, Bid
FROM AUDCAD
WHERE Time LIKE '2016.10.05 *'
ORDER BY ID;
```

should work. Alternatively, you could use the ALIKE ("ANSI LIKE") keyword with the percent (`%`) wildcard:

```sql
SELECT Time, Ask, Bid
FROM AUDCAD
WHERE Time ALIKE '2016.10.05 %'
ORDER BY ID;
```